BuddyPress/Wordpress List all groups
I've created a shortcode to list all groups. But it's not a loop, it only lists the first group created.
function list_groups_shortcode($group) {

    return "<div><h2 align='center'>Groups</h2><button type='button' class='groupButton'><a href='" . bp_get_group_permalink( $group ) . "'>" . bp_get_group_name( $group ) . "</a></div>";
}
add_shortcode('groups', 'list_groups_shortcode');

Any help how to list all buddypress groups in a button and link to that group?
I tried the above code. It only lists one group in a button, not the array of groups.

I don't use BuddyPress, but I believe you are looking for BP_Groups_Group::get()

My php knowledge is limited...how would I use it to achieve the required outcome? Thanks

Use groups_get_groups. Example shortcode: [list_groups]
function list_groups_shortcode() {

    $groups = groups_get_groups( array(
        'per_page'      => 99,
        'show_hidden'   => true,
    ) );

    $groups = $groups['groups'];

    $list = '<div><h2 align='center'>Groups</h2>';
    
    foreach ( $groups as $group ) {
    
        $list .= '<br>' . "<button type='button' class='groupButton'><a href='" . bp_get_group_permalink( $group ) . "'>" . $group->name . '</a>';

    }

    $list .= '</div>';

    return $list;
    
}
add_shortcode('list_groups', 'list_groups_shortcode');


Thanks! I only changed the quotation marks for $list i.e  $list = "Groups".....thanks a bunch works perfectly!
